# Change Supervisor and Candidate in Beamer(TorinoTh)

Tags: beamer

I try to change Supervisor and Candidate in this code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[titlepagelogo=logopolito]{TorinoTh}
\author{name-of-the-author}
\rel{name-of-the-supervisor}
\title{title-of-your-thesis}
\ateneo{name-of-your-University}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\titlepageframe
\begin{tframe}{title-of-the-frame}
text
\end{tframe}
\end{document}
```

by `\setrellabel{Advisor}` and
`\setcandidatelabel{By}` (see [Beamer2Thesis - Thesis theme for Beamer](http://cfiandra.github.io/Beamer2Thesis/)). But I cannot run this code. Help me please.

Comment: What's the error message you get?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I understand, the commands `\setrellabel` and `\setcandidatelabel` are available (and mandatory) *only* if the main language is neither English nor Italian.

With those languages active, they are not defined (which is wrong, in my opinion).

Here's a patch:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[
  language=english,
  titlepagelogo=logopolito
]{TorinoTh}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\beamer@torinoth@superv{Advisor}
\renewcommand\beamer@torinoth@cand{\raisebox{-\depth}[0pt][0pt]{By}}
\makeatother

\author{name-of-the-author}
\rel{name-of-the-supervisor}
\title{title-of-your-thesis}
\ateneo{name-of-your-University}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\titlepageframe
\begin{tframe}{title-of-the-frame}
text
\end{tframe}
\end{document}
```

The horrible `\raisebox` command is due to the fact that, without it, “Advisor” and “By” would not be vertically aligned to each other. `:-(`

[image]