# Trouble with the TorinoTh beamer

Tags: beamer

I'm trying to use `TorinoTh` as my presentation template because this template can display my name and the name of my adviser side by side on the title page, which `Warsaw` seemingly fails to accomplish. To be straight, I'd like my title page to be:

[image]

This can be accomplished by compiling with *Texmaker*:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[language=english,coding=utf8x,titlepagelogo=a-herd-of-boars,bullet=circle,pageofpages=of,titleline=true,color=red]{TorinoTh}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\beamer@torinoth@superv{Adviser}
\renewcommand\beamer@torinoth@cand{\raisebox{-\depth}[0pt][0pt]{Student}}
\makeatother
\author{Junior Boar, R20210901}
\rel{Senior Boar, PhD}
\title{A Brief History of Boar}
\ateneo{National Boar University}
\date{\today}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
\titlepageframe
\begin{tframe}{Outline}
This is the outline of my thesis presentation.
\end{tframe}
\begin{tframe}{Quasi-local mass}
\begin{theorem}
Every little boar likes to compute
\[1+1=2.\]
\end{theorem}
\end{tframe}
\end{document}
```

However, this comes with a fair share of Warning's and Badbox's, which confuses me a lot:

[image]

Is there a way to get rid of these disturbing messages? Or is it possible to produce the same title page with the familiar `Warsaw` theme? Thanks for help!

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: Why run `\renewcommand\beamer@torinoth@cand{\raisebox{-\depth}[0pt][0pt]{Student}}` when `\renewcommand\beamer@torinoth@cand{Student}` will do just as well?

Comment: @Mico You are right: in the *Student* case, we don't need `raisebox` to make good alignment. But somehow we can't work in the *By* case without it, which you will see by visiting the answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235061/change-supervisor-and-candidate-in-beamertorinoth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a similar layout using the `Warsaw` theme (needs beamer v3.70 or newer):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\author{Junior Boar, R20210901}
\title{A Brief History of Boar}
\institute{National Boar University}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}}

\setbeamercolor{institute}{parent=title}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\large}

\setbeamertemplate{author}{
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
      \centering
      Advisor
      
      Senior Boar, PhD
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
      \centering
      Student
      
      Junior Boar
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
  \centering
  \usebeamertemplate{institute}
  \vfill
  \usebeamertemplate{titlegraphic}
  \vfill
  \usebeamertemplate{title}
  \vfill
  \usebeamertemplate{author}
  \vfill
  \usebeamertemplate{date}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, and that will be *A Brief History of Duck*, etc.

Comment: Just wondering, is there a problem with the printing of the student ID?

Comment: @Boar You're welcome! (... and great title :) )

Comment: @Boar Yes, there is a major problem with the student ID: I was too lazy to type or copy it, but I trust your skills to search for `junior boar` and add the ID there :)